# How do I use the True Type Font that has a space in the name in an SLD?

Tags: geoserver, sld, font

Using [an answer from another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24909/7627), I learned how to use a Wingdings character in my point SLD.  Now, I'd like to use a character from "Wingdings 3".

Here's the XML from the answer above that works great with Wingdings.  (I switched the character to 116 as I want a triangle.

```
<Graphic>
  <Mark>
    <WellKnownName>ttf://Wingdings#116</WellKnownName>
    <Fill>
      <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
    </Fill>
  </Mark>
  <Opacity>1</Opacity>
  <Size>18</Size>
</Graphic>
```

Some of the combinations I've tried.

- `ttf://Wingdings3#116`
- `ttf://Wingdings 3#116`
- `ttf://Wingdings$203#116`
- `ttf://Wingdings+3#116`
- `ttf://Wingdings_3#116`
- `ttf://WINGDNG3#116`

What combination am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/0e6fc022f395194e7670b63d2de785123a178cdf/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/renderer/style/TTFMarkFactory.java#L72) there is nothing there that makes a special case for spaces. So I would guess `ttf://Windings 3#116`.

Are you sure that is **exactly** what the JVM calls it on your server. You can check by going to `Server Status` -> `Available Fonts`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip to look in "Available Fonts".  Turns out, "Wingdings 3" is not in the list.  I did just install it, so I restarted the service.  Still not there.  Most likely my problem.

Comment: I did however try "Arial Black", and a character did show up, so you are right, a space character is the answer.  Now the question is getting the Wingdings 3 font in the list...

Comment: Despite being installed on Windows, I had to place the font in `jre/lib/fonts` before it was picked up by Geoserver.  After that, worked perfectly.